# probability of the statement

Tags: probability

A speaks truth 3 times out of 4 and B 7 times out of 10 , they both agree that a white ball has been drawn out from a bag containing 6 different colour balls . Then we have to find what is the probability that the statement is true .

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the bag contains $6$ different balls with $6$ different colors and one of them is white

$$\begin{align}
P(\text{truth}|\text{both say w})&=P(\text{w}|\text{both say w})\\[10pt]
&=\frac{P(\text{both say w}|\text{w})P(\text{w})}{P(\text{both say w}|\text{w})P(\text{w})+P(\text{both say w}|\text{not w})P(\text{not w})}\\[10pt]
&=\frac{(\frac3 4)(\frac{7}{10})(\frac{1}{6})}{(\frac3 4)(\frac{7}{10})(\frac{1}{6})+(\frac1 4)(\frac{3}{10})(\frac{5}{6})}=\frac{7}{12}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Does it make sense?

Comment: But the answer is 35/36

Comment: @user123733 How did you find that answer?